# Scrolling in browser cause slow fetch(url) responses

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

**[context] - this turned out to be irrelevant, the issue at hand is a client side thing**

I'm experiencing some strange response times from my NodeJS/Express app.
According to the logs, the requests complete in 180-220 MS

[image]

But from the web client perspective, I'm seeing these numbers which are very strange, some are in the range of seconds. and the payload is not that big. its around 1.5k.

I've disabled every feature I could suspect, Sessions, AD Authentication etc.

[image]

To add to the confusion, the overhead is only there sometimes, maybe 30% of the requests. others complete in the same time range as listed in the first picture.

I wish I could give more context but it's a really simple React frontend using Fetch to HTTP GET data from the /contacts endpoint.

Nothing more.

**[EDIT 1]**

This seems to be a client side thing.

The whole process is part of a virtual/infinite scroll React component.
If I do scroll down using the down arrow key, response times stay normal.

If I scroll really fast using the scrollbar/touch, the response time goes up.
Important to know is that the services do not return more data, it is always 20 rows at a time, yet the response time increases.

So, does scrolling in a browser somehow prevent promises or other more native constructs from completing?

**[EDIT 2]**

Same behavior across Chrome, Safari, Firefox.
Scrolling fast seems to make the request unable to complete in a timely manner.
Upgrading to React 16 seems to have improved the issue, or maybe just false positives.

**[EDIT 3]**

Even when replacing the call to the backend to a static JSON service online. the behavior still persists, so this has nothing to do with Express or NodeJS.

There is something odd about scrolling and React+Fetch.

**[EDIT 4]**

Client side code snippets:

### Event listeners

```
this.scrollHandler = this.checkWindowScroll;
this.resizeHandler = this.checkWindowScroll;

window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler, { passive: true });
window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeHandler, { passive: true });
```

### ScrollHandler

```
 //check if we have scrolled to the bottom of the screen
 checkWindowScroll = () => {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return;
  }
  const trigger = 800;
  const pageBottom =
    window.document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height - trigger;

  const scrollBottom = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

  if (scrollBottom > pageBottom) {
    this.loadMore();
  }
};
```

### Fetch Next Data

```
//responsible for fetching another chunk of data from a backend
async loadMore() {
  this.setState({ loading: true, error: undefined }); // begin load
  const items = await this.props.fetchData(
    this.search,
    this.state.items.length
  );

  this.setState(
    {
      loading: false,
      error: undefined,
      items: [...this.state.items, ...items] // clone
    },
    () => this.checkWindowScroll() // once state is updated, check again if we need more data
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this from a remote server or localhost?

Comment: I get the same behavior on local, remote, docker.

Comment: Are you using `res.write()` ?

Comment: No, just `res.json(data);`

Comment: The plot thickens, it seems to be a client side issue / React related.
This is part of a "virtual/infinite scroll table".

If I scroll using the keys, the latency is consistent.
If I scroll using the scrollbar or mousepad, I can get higher responsetimes  depending on how fast I scroll.

Bear in mind, each result is 20 rows, so still given the same result size, each chunk loaded takes longer.

Comment: Is there anything funky going on at browser level when scrolling, not completing promises or something?

Comment: If it is not related to Node/Express maybe there is something going on with `fetch`, I would give a chance to `axios` for these kind of edge cases. On the other hand, you can take a look here for Express performance best practices: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html @RogerJohansson

Comment: Is this consistent in multiple browsers? I would suspect it might have something to do with the `fetch` implementation for the browser you are using. Also, have you tried it with the base `XMLHttpRequest` object instead of `fetch`?

Comment: Same behavior across Chrome, Safari, Firefox.  It is better in Chrome, but still there.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is your [scroll event listener passive](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)?  Can you show some of your front end code?

Comment: I've added some snippets from my code to the post

Comment: Something is seriously iffy with setState being async here, the re-render triggers long over due

Comment: The issue is now solved.
The problem was caused by multiple factors.

As @zero298 pointed out, the handler should be passive.
Another major issue was that React handles rendering of long lists poorly.
by pre-rendering each row once the data arrives, the performance increased a lot.